# Every Derive table must have its own alias in mysql

Tags: mysql

i want to delete all records except max 3 on basic of visitdate

```
Delete from IPADDRESS 
where visitdate Not in (
  SELECT visitdate FROM (
    SELECT visitdate FROM IPADDRESS 
    WHERE USERNAME='MGSH0002' ORDER BY visitdate DESC)
  where ROWNUM < 4) and 
USERNAME='MGSH0002'
```

Comment: my problm is still unsolved plz help me how can run this query in my sql"Delete from IPADDRESS  where visitdate Not in (   SELECT visitdate FROM (     SELECT visitdate FROM IPADDRESS      WHERE USERNAME='MGSH0002' ORDER BY visitdate DESC)   where ROWNUM < 4) and  USERNAME='MGSH0002' "

Comment: No, forget my previous comments. The questions are not the same, similar but not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code with some (any) formatting and the problem will be more obvious. It also helps MySQL to provide an error that can help you more (like: `error in line 8: ...`).

```
Delete from IPADDRESS 
where visitdate Not in 
      ( SELECT visitdate 
        FROM 
          ( SELECT visitdate                --- this is
            FROM IPADDRESS                  --- the
            WHERE USERNAME='MGSH0002'       --- derived
            ORDER BY visitdate DESC         --- table
          )  x                         --- alias `x` added
        where ROWNUM < 4
      )  
  and USERNAME='MGSH0002'
```

But I don't think that MySQL has `ROWNUM`. Are you sure this is for MySQL and not Oracle? Because MySQL has some limitations on `DELETE` and referencing the table to be deleted in `WHERE`. You could use something like:

```
DELETE i
FROM 
      IpAddress AS i
  CROSS JOIN
      ( SELECT visitdate 
        FROM IpAddress 
        WHERE username = 'MGSH0002'
        ORDER BY visitdate DESC 
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
      ) AS tmp
WHERE i.username = 'MGSH0002'
  AND i.visitdate < tmp.visitdate
```

Comment: thnk u 4 ans.. but not rumning in mysql..i got error unkown "colum'ROWNUM' in where clause" is there any alternate for RONUM in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving each sub-query an alias, such as

```
Delete from IPADDRESS 
where visitdate Not in (
  SELECT visitdate FROM (
    SELECT visitdate FROM IPADDRESS 
    WHERE USERNAME='MGSH0002' ORDER BY visitdate DESC) as ip_address
  where ROWNUM < 4) as ip_address_ordered and 
USERNAME='MGSH0002'
```

Comment: yes but "ROWNUM" does not work in mysql otherwise query is fine